# Why is `(True, True, True) == True, True, True` not True in Python?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

Code snippet 1:

```
a = True, True, True
b = (True, True, True)

print(a == b)
```

returns `True`.

Code snippet 2:

```
(True, True, True) == True, True, True
```

returns `(False, True, True)`.

Comment: It's equivalent to ((1, 1, 1) == 1), 1, 1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). You're actually checking equality between `(True, True, True)` and `True` in your second code snippet, and then building a tuple with that result as the first item.

Recall that in Python by specifying a comma-separated "list" of items without any brackets, it returns a tuple:

```
>>> a = True, True, True
>>> print(type(a))
<class 'tuple'>
>>> print(a)
(True, True, True)
```

Code snippet 2 is no exception here. You're attempting to build a tuple using the same syntax, it just so happens that the first element is `(True, True, True) == True`, the second element is `True`, and the third element is `True`.

So code snippet 2 is equivalent to:

`(((True, True, True) == True), True, True)`

And since `(True, True, True) == True` is False (you're comparing a tuple of three objects to a boolean here), the first element becomes False.

Comment: ohh, can you pls also explain how it returns  `(False, True, True)`

Comment: @NanduRaj Added to answer, but basically you're comparing a tuple of booleans to a boolean itself. Just because all the values are truthy in the tuple doesn't mean the expression itself is true :) (And if you'd want to check that, you'd use `all((True, True, True))`

Comment: Yeah I got the `first element becomes False` part. Why second element is True? Thanks for your answer :) @TerryA

Comment: for me even more confusing 
True, True, True  == True, True, True
gives
(True, True, True, True, True)

Comment: @NanduRaj Because code snippet 2 is ultimately just an expression that's building a tuple. The first element is False (because of the comparison), the second element is `True` (because that's what's specified), and the third element is `True` (same reason as second element)

Comment: @MoHuss Yes, again operator precedence. That's equivalent to `(True, True, (True == True), True, True)`

Comment: @MoHuss you can achieve that with this: `a = True, True, True; b = True, True, True`. Now `a == b` gives you `True`.

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with how expressions are evaluated in python.

In the first case, both `a` and `b` are tuples.

```
a = True, True, True
b = (True, True, True)

print(type(a))
print(type(b))

print(a == b)
```

Out:

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
True
```

So, they are compared as tuples and in-fact they are both equal in value.

But for case 2, it's evaluated left to right.

```
(True, True, True) == True, True, True
```

First the tuple `(True, True, True)` is compared with just `True` which is `False`.

Comment: Why the second element in output `True`

Comment: because, there is a True already there. The last two Trues are evaluated as they are. The final output is a tuple.